# Display hyperlink in <td> based on condition in google sitebricks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sitebricks

I am using Google Sitebricks for developing a user interface.

I have a table which i am displaying using @repeat annotation

@Repeat(items=regusers, var="reguser")

```
<tr>
<td><a href="/something/${reguser.userId}">${reguser.userId}</a></td>
<td>${reguser.userRegAt}</td>      
</tr>
```

I have a 'status' variable .based on this value i wanna toggle display of anchor tag in       first column

can you please point me to a solution .

Thanks .  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following

```
<tr>

@ShowIf(status)
<td><a href="/something/${reguser.userId}">${reguser.userId}</a></td>

<td>${reguser.userRegAt}</td>
</tr>
```